# seen from the helicopter VS seeing from the helicopter

Tags: grammaticality, syntax, semantics

> Seen from the helicopter, the cars on the road are as small as insects.

> We seeing the cars on the road from the helicopter, they are as small as insects.

Are both of the sentences grammatically and semantically correct?

In my opinion, the first sentence is fine, but the second one seems weird and incorrect.

Comment: "we seeing" does not work at all.

Comment: If you particularly want to use _we_ as subject, you have to express it differently - something like "From the helicopter, we see the cars on the road looking as small as insects".

Comment: @Lambie, I agree.  Someone said the second example involved  Absolute Nominative Constructions, but  I don't think so.  Can you explain the conditions in usage about this construction?

Comment: @Lambie, or can I say, " The cars on the road seen from the helicopter, they are as small as insects"?

Comment: This is a good question.  Absolute Construction makes it seem like we should be able to say "We seeing the cars, (something)", but that doesn't work.

Comment: @stangdon, Thanks.  " The homework done, Jack left" is an example of Absolute Construction, right?

Comment: Seeing the cars on the road from above, they looked etc.

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks for your illustration. If so, can I correct the second example by changing it into this : Seeing the cars on the road from the helicopter, they looked as small as insects?  If yes, a new question arises, what about " Seen from the helicopter, the cars on the road looked as small as insects" ?

Comment: seeing or seen can be used as a **participle phrase** here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1

> Seen from the helicopter, the cars on the road are as small as insects.

*Seen from the helicopter* is a participial phrase and modifies *cars*.  Example 1 works.

2

> We seeing the cars on the road from the helicopter, they are as small as insects.

*We seeing the cars on the road from the helicopter* does not modify *they*.  Another problem with this example is faulty pronoun reference; *they* has no antecedent.  This example hence does not work.

Similarly, removing *We*, leaving the participial phrase *seeing the cars on the road from the helicopter* does not help.  This phrase does not modify *they*, and we have the same faulty pronoun reference problem.

As absolute construction has been brought up, we attempt to see its possibility.

An absolute phrase usually consists of a **noun/pronoun** followed and modified by a **modifier**, usually a participle/participial phrase.

An absolute phrase

> is absolute because it modifies no single word in the main sentence; however, it has a **close “thought” relationship to the entire main sentence** [emphasis added].

An absolute phrase

> **modifies the rest of the sentence** [emphasis added], not the subject of the sentence as opposed to a participial phrase.

In the following examples from [ifioque](https://ifioque.com/phrases/nominative-absolute), the respective absolute phrases modify their independent clauses.

> The book being short, I read it in two hours.

> The paint now dry, we brought the furniture out on the deck.

[guidetogrammar](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/phrases.htm) gives more explanation and examples.

> Absolute phrases do not directly connect to or modify any specific word in the rest of the sentence; instead, they modify the entire sentence, adding information.

> The season nearly finished, Rebecca Lobo and Sophie Witherspoon emerged as true leaders.

> The two superstars signed autographs into the night, their faces beaming happily.

The example in OP's comments is an absolute construction.

> The homework done, Jack left.

For our 2nd *car* example, however, I do not see a possibility of an absolute construction.

Answer (score 0):

Participle phrases:

Seeing the cars on the road from the helicopter, they looked as small as insects.

Seen from the helicopter, the cars on the road etc.
OR
The cars seen from the helicopter looked very small.

[participle phrases](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html)